# How do I make ansible assemble output the assembled file only on my local machine?

Tags: ansible

My current playbook does the following.

1. Creates a file in /tmp named after the current host.
2. Fetches all of the previously created files from the remote hosts and puts them in a directory on the master.
3. This is where I'm running into trouble. I'd like to combine all of these files into one only on the controller. I tried to do this using assemble and it worked.... But it placed the assembled file on all of the remote hosts, not the master. How do I do this but only combine the files at the destination specified on the master, excluding remote hosts?

```
---
- block: 
    
    - shell: |
        cd /tmp
        echo {{ inventory_hostname }} > {{ inventory_hostname }}-Info.txt

    - ansible.builtin.fetch:
        src: /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}-Info.txt
        dest: /tmp/gatheredFiles/
        flat: yes 

# Creating the file on all remote hosts, not on the master machine.
    - ansible.builtin.assemble:
        src: /tmp/gatheredFiles
        dest: /tmp/combinedFile.txt
        delimiter: '######'
        remote_src: false 

      

  # when: "'condition' in ansible_hostname"
```

Comment: Your code works as expected. The assembled file is created on the controller. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options here.

### Use a separate play

Perhaps the simplest solution is to move the `assemble` task to a separate play that only targets `localhost`:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - shell: |
        cd /tmp
        echo {{ inventory_hostname }} > {{ inventory_hostname }}-Info.txt

    - ansible.builtin.fetch:
        src: /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}-Info.txt
        dest: /tmp/gatheredFiles/
        flat: yes 

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    # Creating the file on all remote hosts, not on the master machine.
    - ansible.builtin.assemble:
        src: /tmp/gatheredFiles
        dest: /tmp/combinedFile.txt
        delimiter: '######'
        remote_src: false
```

### Use delegation

Alternatively, you can probably combine `delegate_to` and `run_once` to achieve the same thing:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - shell: |
        cd /tmp
        echo {{ inventory_hostname }} > {{ inventory_hostname }}-Info.txt

    - ansible.builtin.fetch:
        src: /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}-Info.txt
        dest: /tmp/gatheredFiles/
        flat: yes 

    # Creating the file on all remote hosts, not on the master machine.
    - delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      ansible.builtin.assemble:
        src: /tmp/gatheredFiles
        dest: /tmp/combinedFile.txt
        delimiter: '######'
        remote_src: false
```

Comment: Delegating to local fixed my issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
test_11
test_13
```

You code

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - shell: |
        cd /tmp
        echo {{ inventory_hostname }} > {{ inventory_hostname }}-Info.txt
    - fetch:
        src: /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}-Info.txt
        dest: /tmp/gatheredFiles/
        flat: yes
    - assemble:
        src: /tmp/gatheredFiles
        dest: /tmp/combinedFile.txt
        remote_src: false
```

works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [shell] **********************************************************************************
changed: [test_13]
changed: [test_11]

TASK [fetch] **********************************************************************************
changed: [test_13]
changed: [test_11]

TASK [assemble] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_13]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=3    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=3    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

The files at the remote hosts were created

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/test_11-Info.txt
test_11
shell> ssh admin@test_13 cat /tmp/test_13-Info.txt
test_13
```

, fetched to the controller

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/gatheredFiles/
/tmp/gatheredFiles/
├── test_11-Info.txt
└── test_13-Info.txt
```

, and the contents were assembled

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/combinedFile.txt 
test_11
test_13
```

The only improvement would be running the *assemble* task once

```yaml
    - assemble:
        src: /tmp/gatheredFiles
        dest: /tmp/combinedFile.txt
        remote_src: false
      run_once: true
```